# Difference between $em->find(..) and $em->getRepository(..)->find(..)

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

There is Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Some\Namspace\CustomRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="image_type")
 */
class MyEntity{...}
```

and CustomRepository extends EntityRepository to override some methods like `find` or `findAll`

documentation says:

> ```
> // $em instanceof EntityManager
> $user = $em->find('MyProject\Domain\User', $id);
> ```
>
> Essentially, EntityManager#find() is just a shortcut for the following:
>
> ```
> $user = $em->getRepository('MyProject\Domain\User')->find($id);
> ```

[link:doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-primary-key)

but my `CustomRepository` works only with `$em->getRepository('Entities\MyEntity')->find($id)`

using `$em->find('Entities\MyEntity',$id);` ignoring my overrided methods in `CustomRepository`

---

- so is this a bug?
- or there's a difference between this construcions?
- how can i overide `find`,`finAll`,`...` methods for my entity without overriding EntityManager?

---

Edit (1)

using composer:

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.4"
},
```

`find` code:

```
public function find($entityName, $id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
{
    $class = $this->metadataFactory->getMetadataFor(ltrim($entityName, '\\'));

    if ( ! is_array($id)) {
        if ($class->isIdentifierComposite) {
            throw ORMInvalidArgumentException::invalidCompositeIdentifier();
        }

        $id = array($class->identifier[0] => $id);
    }
    ........... other ~100 lines
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In doctrine 2.2 it doesn't seem to be any different - literally just a pass-through/shortcut for `getRepository()->find()`

http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#348

```
public function find($entityName, $identifier, $lockMode = LockMode::NONE, $lockVersion = null)
{
    return $this->getRepository($entityName)->find($identifier, $lockMode, $lockVersion);
}
```

Thoughts:

- What version of doctrine?
- Any chance you have a customized EntityManager?

Comment: using composer: "require": {"doctrine/orm": "~2.4"}, got other code (i'll update my quastion in moment)

Comment: Code is different for Doctrine ORM <=2.2 and >=2.3, but basically it reverses the behavior to make it be done by the EntityManager instead of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Note: the behavior explained here is for Doctrine ORM 2.3+.
In 2.2 and before, it was the "reverse" one.

> so is this a bug?

Nope, it's just a way to use the Entity manager "faster" without loading the repository. But behind, the repository loads the EntityManager to execute the `find` method.

> or there's a difference between this construcions?

Performances, maybe, but actually maybe need a bench on this.
But basically, it's **exactly the same**

What `$em->find(...)` does:
Load a single entity by its primary key.

What `$em->getRepository(...)->find(...)` does:
It runs this: `return $this->_em->find($this->_entityName, $id, $lockMode, $lockVersion);`.
So it loads the `$em->find(...)` method.
So it's the same :)

> how can i overide `find`,`findAll`, ... methods for my entity without overriding EntityManager?

Create a custom repository, either per-entity.

If you do this per-entity, you'll have to add the "repositoryClass" option in the "@Entity" annotation, and specify the Repository class in it, so you'll be able to override every method only for this entity.

[See the docs to know more about custom repository use](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

You can also do it globally. Create your own EntityRepository, make it extend the `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` class, and you can override the different functions.
Here is an example of an EntityRepository that is overriding the Doctrine's default repository, on [Orbitale/ToolsBundle:BaseEntityRepository.php](https://github.com/Orbitale/DoctrineTools/blob/master/BaseEntityRepository.php), but if you want to do this, you'll have to change the "default repository class name" in the ORM's configuration.

You don't have to override the EntityManager, it's powerful enough to be used directly as-is, and it does many things internally that should never be broken when doing fuzzy stuff in overriding it.

Comment: i'm using `RepositoryClass` and don't want to change base repository class name. only want to use myown EntityManager `find`,`...` methods.

this quastion refers to my another quastion, where i'm trying to resolve my problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336832/force-doctrine-to-load-all-records-from-table-trying-to-access-one-of-them)

Comment: What kind of stuff do you want to override in the `EntityManager::find` method?
 
Basically you should be able to do it in a Repository.
If you want to do it for **every** repository, then do it globally by creating a custom entity repository and override the `doctrine: { orm: { default_repository_class: "" } } ` yml parameter

Comment: in link above I'm making library that can extend user defined entities with my `MappedSuperclass` in lib. `MappedSuperclass` named GraphNode that provides connection between nodes in graph. I want to create simple way to work with nodes and links, so i don't know what method used by user `EntityManager::find()` or `EntityManager::getRepository()::find()`, but i need to override methods `find` and other to preload all Graph data and link nodes each other for better performance before returning user entity from EntityManager or my custom repository.